# Reset password at user's first login

Tags: php

```
<?php
include("config.php");

session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
  // username and password sent from Form
  $myusername = addslashes($_POST['username']);
  $mypassword = addslashes($_POST['password']);

  $sql = 'SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = "'.$myusername.'" and password = "'.$mypassword.'" ';

  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $active = $row['active'];
  $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

  // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
  if ($count==1)
  {
    $session_id = $row['user_id'];
    session_register("session_id");
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $session_id;
    $login_session = $_SESSION['login_user'];
    header("location:resetpwd.php?user_session=".$login_session."");
  }
  else
  { echo "invalid username/password"; }  
}
?>

<html>
 <body>

   <form action='' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>  
      <table class="login">
       <tr><td><label>Username </label></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="username" maxlength="20" size="30px"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr><td><label>Password </label></td>
           <td><input type="password" name="password"  maxlength="50" size="30px"/></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <div><input type="submit" class="loginbutton" style="cursor:pointer;" value=""/></div>  
   </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

The above code is a login page. When a user registers, he/she will get an auto generated password to his/her mail. Now the user will login with that username and password from email, I need to redirect the page to change to password only at first time login and later  it should redirect to welcome.php

Could anyone suggest me. Many Thanks

Comment: `addslashes` wont protect you from sql injection, `session_register` & `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, using plaintext passwords, your not exiting after `header`, not using a doctype, using tables for structure, using single quotes for html properties. eek! whats right ;p

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Could you please tell: instead of session_register, what is new one we could use. And what is the best way to store variables that protects my code from Sql injections

Comment: `session_register` not needed. [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a database column saying "is first login". Alternatively, you can have a "most recent login", and if it's null then they've never logged in before and need to set a password.

Or just do what normal people do and have "password" be a field on the registration form.

Comment: Could you please brief out with a sort of php coding. Please don't mind.

Comment: *"Have a database column saying "is first login"."* --- That should be `is_first_login` and `most_recent_login` because then, the OP would be forced to wrap the column with backticks when querying. *Just saying* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I always backtick. Not doing so is akin to writing `$foo = bar;` in PHP.

Comment: You always backtick (*great*), but does the OP? *ah* ;-)